# How do I set a default action for a rich notification?

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

I understand how to set the specific actions for a notification using UNNotificationAction and display those if the user opens the long look of the notification. But if the just swipe on the notification, how do I set how that action is handled? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but this is my first time working with push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

If the user just taps your notification then the standard AppDelegate method will be called, and you can perform your "default" action.